# Is $\sigma_1 I_A + \sigma_2 I_{A^c}$ a stopping time for stopping times $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and $A\in\mathscr{F}_{n+1}$, $n\geq 0$?

Tags: stopping-times

Let $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ be stopping times
of a filtration $(\mathscr{F}_n)^\infty_{n=0}$,
and let $A\in\mathscr{F}_{n+1}$ for some $n\geq 0$.

**Question:** Is $\sigma_3 = \sigma_1 I_A + \sigma_2 I_{A^c}$ a stopping time?
Here $A^c$ is the complement of $A$,
and $I_A$ equals $1$ on $A$ and equals $0$ otherwise.

I am reading Peskir and Shiryaev's "Optimal Stopping and Free-Boundary Problems".
On page 9 it is claimed that $\sigma_3$ lies in the set
$\mathfrak{M}_{n+1}$
of stopping times $T$ satisfying $T\geq n+1$
when $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ lie in $\mathfrak{M}_{n+1}$
and $A$ is the set on which
$\mathbb{E}[G_{\sigma_1}|\mathscr{F}_{n+1}]\geq\mathbb{E}[G_{\sigma_2}|\mathscr{F}_{n+1}]$,
where $(G_t)^\infty_{t=0}$ is an adapted process.

What I think matters here is that $A$ lies in $\mathscr{F}_{n+1}$
and that $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are stopping times.
I know that the sum of two stopping times again is a stopping time.
So if I can show that $\sigma_1 I_A$ and $\sigma_2 I_{A^c}$ are stopping times
then I know that $\sigma_3$ is a stopping time.

However, if I am not mistaken then for each $t\in\mathbb{N}$ it holds that
\begin{equation*}
\{\sigma_1 I_A\leq t\} = \{\sigma_1\leq t\}\cup A^c,
\end{equation*}
which for $t < n+1$
is a union of an element in $\mathscr{F}_t$
and an element in $\mathscr{F}_{n+1}$,
hence possibly not an element in $\mathscr{F}_t$.
In other words,
$\sigma_1 I_A$ may not be a stopping time!

What am I missing here to see that $\sigma_3$ is a stopping time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is important that $\sigma_1, \sigma_2  \ge n+1$.

Example.  Deterministic $\sigma_1 = 1, \sigma_2 = 2$ are of course stopping times.
But if $A \in \mathscr F_{n+1} \setminus \mathscr F_2$, what about
$\sigma_3 := \sigma_1 I_A + \sigma_2 I_{A^c}
$?  Compute

$$
\{\sigma_3 \le 1\} = A \notin \mathscr F_1 .
$$

so $\sigma_3$ is not a stopping time.